# How to get 'content' of post records stored in db using id

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to get content from a h2 database using the post id attached to those records. I can pull the results using normal findAll(), but when I try using an Id, I am not able to any records

This is my controller

```
@GetMapping("{id}")
PostDetails getPostDetails(@PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
    return postService.getPostDetails(id);
}
```

These are my models
My Post model

```
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
}
```

My Postdetails class which extends postinfo

```
@Data
@ToString
public class PostDetails extends PostInfo {
    private String content;
}
```

My Postinfo class

```
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
public class PostInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
}
```

My PostService service class

```
public interface PostService {

    PostDetails createPost(@Valid CreatePostRequest createPostRequest);

    Page<PostInfo>getPosts(final Pageable pageable);

    PostDetails getPostDetails(Long id);

    void deletePost(Long id);
}
```

My Repository is as:

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
}
```

My Implementation class

```
@Override
    public PostDetails getPostDetails(Long id) {
        return postRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
```

I end up not getting any data. How can I use findById to the content(from PostDetails). I have researched with no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would really appreciate some help on this

Comment: Do you got some error or 404?

Comment: I couldn't see anything with no more details... Try this  @GetMapping("/{id}")  with slash and public in your method....